# ogr2ogr: Transformation from NAD27 to WGS84 not working

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr, tolerance

I'm trying to use ogr2ogr to transform from NAD27 to WGS84 and check the precision afterwards.
For that, I used a GML file with coordinates -124.0, 48.0

It looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4267"
      }
    },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -124.0,
          48.0
        ]
      },
      "properties": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I tried to convert it using ogr2ogr by running this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -s_srs EPSG:4267 -t_srs EPSG:4326 output.geojson input.geojson
```

It returned the same coordinates **-124.0, 48.0**:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "crs":{
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{
         "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
      }
   },
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{

         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -124.0,
               48.0
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

However, when I tried to convert between NAD27 and WGS84 using epsg.io web page and called this URL:
http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4267&t_srs=4326

It returned these coordinates: **-124.001314 and 47.9998062**

There is a big difference between both results [-124.0, 48.0] and [-124.001314, 47.9998062] - around **140 meters!**

Does it mean, the ogr2ogr is not precise or I didn't use it properly?

Comment: Geojson is always in 4326 try with another format.

Comment: This is not the issue, for two reasons.  
1) I tried with GML and got the same result.  
2) Also, I tried GeoJSON with another input coordinate system (EPSG:4740) and coordinates [120.0, 60.0] and it did work and did produce correct results.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem with a different library. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think docker version of GDAL worked.